# How can wildcard expansion create duplicates?

Tags: filesystems, tcsh, csh

I have a directory with an absurd number of files, which makes this nigh impossible to understand by inspection.  But here's the situation:

```
cp giant_folder/pre* myfolder
```

It's crunching along and starts generating warnings like:

```
cp: warning: source file 'giant_folder/pre1234.txt' specified more than once
```

How can this happen?

Comment: That shouldn't be possible

Answer (score 1):

You *could* replace `cp` with `echo` to see the expansions, but there's a better way of dealing with "an absurd number of files". Read `man find xargs cp`, and do something like:

```
find giant_folder -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'pre*' -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -r cp -t myfolder
```

This will pack as many filenames as it can on a line, and execute as many `cp` commands as it needs. See `xargs --show-limits </dev/null`.

Comment: It doesn't explain the error, though, and if the error report is true then your code will still copy _N_ files to _M_ destinations, where _M < N_

Comment: I discovered that some files matching the wildcard were not copied either, but they aren't the ones referenced in the error messages.  Mysterious to me.  If the command line got too long, my understanding is that there should be an error because the destination folder would be cut off.